# Prove that all points of an open set are limit points of that set.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, proof-writing

I would like to find out if my proof is alright or if it is missing any steps...thanks.

$B$ is a non-empty open set. Show that every point in $B$ is a limit point of $B$.

Since $B$ is open, $\forall b \in B$, there exists an $\epsilon$-neighborhood $V_\epsilon (b) \subseteq B$. This means that for all $b \in B$, every single possible $\epsilon$-neighborhood of b intersects $B$ at some point other than $b$. By definition, this means that all elements of B are limit points of B.

Comment: Once again, that is correct. However, note that *every limit point* of the open set need not be inside it.

Comment: Note that this applies to a topological space that has no isolated points , A point $x$ in a space $S$ is an isolated point of $S$ iff $\{x\}$ is open in$S.$

Answer (score 1):

In general it is not true. Consider a nonempty set $X$ with the discrete metric, say $X=\{a,b,c\}$. Than $\{a\}$ is open, but $a$ is not a limit point of $\{a\}$.

PS. The result is true if the open set does not contain isolated points. A subset of a topological space with no isolated points is called *dense-in-itself*. Thus, your result holds for open sets that are dense-in-itself.

PS2. A *closed* dense-in-itself subset is called a *perfect set*. *Open* and dense-in-itself sets, apparently, do not deserve a special name.

Answer (score 0):

That is, for your $V_{\varepsilon}(b)\subset B$, we have $(V_{\varepsilon}(b)\smallsetminus\{b\})\subset V_{\varepsilon}(b)\subset B$. Then $(V_{\varepsilon}(b)\smallsetminus\{b\})\cap B\neq\varnothing$.